# VSCode ssh server fails to install extensions, why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode version: 1.59.0-insider

During server installation I get this error:

```
Acquiring lock on C:\Users\Alexey\.vscode-server-insiders\bin\9520f0a515e7e24802c92f885a0efb242fca3831\vscode-remote-lock.9520f0a515e7e24802c92f885a0efb242fca3831
Looking for existing server in C:\Users\Alexey\.vscode-server-insiders\bin\9520f0a515e7e24802c92f885a0efb242fca3831
Downloading server
4c5214b0e485%%1%%
Expanding server into C:\Users\Alexey\AppData\Local\Temp\o55mu2ub.wxr
4c5214b0e485%%2%%
mv : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Alexey\AppData\Local\Temp\o55mu2ub.wxr\vscode-server-win32-x64\extensions' is denied.
At line:10 char:1
+ mv "$aa_\vscode-*\*" -Destination .
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Alexey...-x64\extensions:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand



    Directory: C:\Users\Alexey\.vscode-server-insiders


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        25/07/2021     19:56              0 .9520f0a515e7e24802c92f885a0efb242fca3831.token
```

This does not stop server from starting successfully, but any extensions fail to install on remote:

```
Unable to resolve non-existing file 'c:\Users\Alexey\.vscode-server-insiders\bin\9520f0a515e7e24802c92f885a0efb242fca3831\extensions'
```

Folder from the error message above does not exist. Manually creating it fixes the problem, at least I have not found anything wrong.

What funny is that this folder remains empty.

Is there a way to fix this? Always connecting to the remote and creating this folder manually does not work for me.

Both remote and client machines run Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe trying to run VS Code as administrator could help. The user of the code editor might have not sufficient rights to write the folder.

Comment: Tried, this gave no effect at all.